# Drupal 7:replace original image with ImageStyles generated image

Tags: php, image, drupal, module

I'm using regular imagefields on various content types in a Drupal 7 social website (and also on the user profile pictures via http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_profiles). For cropping I'm using http://drupal.org/project/imagecrop as an image style effect.

I would like to replace the original image with the one generated from the imagecrop style. How do you replace the original image from a user (the one that gets used for subsequent image styles when you say call it in views) with one that is created from an image style effect?

I'm not sure the best way to approach this problem, which is why I posted question.

To make sure I'm being clear -

1. A User uploads a large image (say 2,000 pixels by 1300 pixels) via a regular imagefield.
2. Using image styles, I perform some effects (specifically javascript crop, but this could be generic) and then replace the original image with the one generated from  the image style.
3. All additional image styles (different sizes etc) use the new original images and are derived from it.

I think this can be done easily using a custom module and they must have used something like the image editor project - See drupal.org/project/imageeditor, just not sure what hooks to use or how to jump in on this. Any advice, tips or direction would be great.

Comment: I opened up an issue here: http://drupal.org/node/1475312 and then found an answer to the specific problem I was trying to solve. The newest version of Image Java Script Crop has an option to reuse previous image style crop settings (cool). I did not however make any real progress on finding a generic way to replace the original image, but I no longer need that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check module - [Original image with style](http://drupal.org/sandbox/xandeadx/1999974)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can address your problem by making changes under the display settings for your field:

/admin/structure/types/manage/[your content type machine name here]/display